# Example of reference counting system in R v4

Tags: r, memory, memory-management

I am trying to understand how the reference counting system in R v4 improves memory usage.

According to https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2019/12/preview-of-r-400.html

> When you delete an object in R, it will usually releases the
>   associated memory back to the operating system. Likewise, if you copy
>   an object with `y <- x`, R won't allocate new memory for y unless x is
>   later modified. In current versions of R, however, that system breaks
>   down if there are more than 2 references to any block of memory.
>   Starting with R 4.0.0, all references will be counted

If I understand this correctly, if I add a `z<-x` then a new location on the memory should be used for at least one of these objects.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

> x<-2
> tracemem(x)
[1] "<000001D961ADBEA8>"
> y<-x
> tracemem(y)
[1] "<000001D961ADBEA8>"
> z<-x
> tracemem(z)
[1] "<000001D961ADBEA8>"
> w<-x
> tracemem(w)
[1] "<000001D961ADBEA8>"
```

this doesn't seem to be the case under R 3.6.2.

Can someone provide an example to show how the reference counting system in R v4 is different from R v3?

Comment: I don't follow this issue closely, but if I understand correctly, this is to change with 4.0? You are currently using 3.6.2.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik according to the link I quoted, using R <v4, this should allocate new memory because I have more than one reference to x. However in my example under R 3.6.2 I don't see any memory being reallocated.

Comment: I think it's more about garbage collection than about saving copies. With ARC in place gc() will have more information on what to garbage collect and what to keep. Previously R had NRC with which R only knew if I should delete it or not. with 0,1,2 being the only option. This could help in better memory management for R

Comment: Modify one of the variables to trigger a copy.  y[1]<-3